# concatenating Columns within a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a large csv file where I have filtered out the rows I want and created smaller more manageable data frames (called 'CL').  Each row has a Contract Month and Contract Year both in Int64 (I believe).  I want to create a column combining the two in a date format (e.g.,  MM-YYYY) and having difficulty.

I have tried both extracting the columns to pandas series and converting to string

```
series.to_string
```

as well as the individual columns with

```
CL['CONTRACT MONTH']= CL['CONTRACT MONTH'].astype(str)
```

The latter method gives me a message "... SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

A little over my head with this (just learning Python) and was hoping for some help.

Comment: Would you want to store the combined date as an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate strings within Pandas series using `+`. In addition, you can use `pd.Series.str.zfill` to ensure months always have 2 characters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 1995], [3, 1996], [2, 1998], [5, 2000]],
                  columns=['MONTH', 'YEAR'])

df['DATE'] = df['MONTH'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '-' + df['YEAR'].astype(str)

print(df)

   MONTH  YEAR     DATE
0     10  1995  10-1995
1      3  1996  03-1996
2      2  1998  02-1998
3      5  2000  05-2000
```

Your `SettingWithCopyWarning` may not represent a problem *per se*. It is often a guess by Pandas that you are operating on a copy rather than a view. You may safely ignore this warning if you see it with the above solution.

Comment: one little snag...if I would want the new 'Date' to be come the index how would I do it?  I tried
    df.set_index(df['DATE'])

but doesn't work.

Comment: @ChrisL, Reassign back to `df`, i.e. `df = df.set_index(df['DATE'])`